# PSD to PNG conversion color does not match

Tags: imagemagick, png, psd

> convert sample.psd[0] out.png

Sample PSD file : [https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zbae636mkkeikd/12788_109282907_1.psd?dl=0]

Comment: Sample PSD file : [https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zbae636mkkeikd/12788_109282907_1.psd?dl=0]

Comment: Your image is CMYK but PNG does not support that. You need to convert your PSD from CMYK to sRGB with profiles when writing to PNG.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use profiles to convert from CMYK to sRGB, since PNG does not support CMYK. You can use profiles in Imagemagick as follows. But you will need to use your own paths to profiles and perhaps download them.

```
convert 12788_109282907_1.psd[0] -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/sRGB.icc 12788_109282907_1.png
```

[image]

You can get some profiles from Imagemagick at https://imagemagick.org/archive/delegates/

Comment: Thanks fmw42. Now it's woking fine